# whindow phone IE-7 java script prb

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have made a webpage. The IE 7 of windows 7 doesn't execute Javascript. How do I enable Javascript on the Windows Phone?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone 7 runs a mobile version of IE9 so there should be no problems executing javascript. The only thing I can think of with the little information is that you are trying to use a webbrowsercontrol from within an application. In that case you should set the `IsScriptEnabled` property to true to enable scripts within the control.

Answer (score 0):

chirag !

In window phone 7, you can enable Javascript.

in xaml , you can set isScriptEnabled= true.

Examle:

```
<phone:WebBrowser HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="480" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Name="webBrowser" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsScriptEnabled="True" ScriptNotify="webBrowser_ScriptNotify" Navigated="webBrowser_Navigated" Navigating="webBrowser_Navigating" />
```

you can use event :

```
private void webBrowser_ScriptNotify(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Controls.NotifyEventArgs e)
        {
            //your code : e is returned from the javascript code if javaScript is active
        }
```

You can down load HTML content by use : webClient or `string htmlcontent = webBrowser.SaveToString`

Hope this help ! Thongaduka